# Exporting a variable to a .csv file

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I extract a list of departments from AD like this using PowerShell:

```
$departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department |
               Where-Object { $_.Department } |
               Select -Expand Department -Unique
```

At the end of this operation, if I input on the console `$departments` I get all the names of the departments as I wished. But if I try to export this to a .csv file using

```
| Export-Csv H:\TEST\DEPTAAAAA.csv
```

I get this

```
#TYPE System.String
Length
4
9
5
13
13
13
```

How can I export the department names stored in the `$departments` so the output is a .csv file containing the department names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Export-Csv` cmdlet exports the properties of the input objects as the fields of the output CSV. Since your input is a list of string objects the output is the property (`Length`) of these objects.

Don't expand the property `Department` if you want to export it via `Export-Csv`:

```
$departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department |
               Where-Object { $_.Department } |
               Select Department -Unique

$departments | Export-Csv 'H:\TEST\DEPTAAAAA.csv'
```

or use `Out-File` instead of `Export-Csv` if you want to write the list of strings to the output file:

```
$departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department |
               Where-Object { $_.Department } |
               Select -Expand Department -Unique

$departments | Out-File 'H:\TEST\DEPTAAAAA.csv'
```