# Difference between using and not using pipe in Export-Csv in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

This is probably more of a 'how does PowerShell handle variables and piping' rather than a specific programmatical question, but since it seems like strange behaviour (to me) I thought I'd post it here.

I just had some difficulties exporting a variable to a CSV using PowerShell and found [this Stack question that helped me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858133/powershell-output-variables-to-text-file/). However, when fiddling around with the output I got two different results depending on how I called the `Export-CSV` function.

I have a custom PS object that looks roughly like this:

```
Account      Partner     ProjectName     ProjectPhase
1            A           Test            Start
2            B           Test2           Start
3            A           Test4           End
4            C           Test3           Middle
....
```

When I use the following line it correctly outputs the CSV file:

```
$csvBody | Export-Csv -Path "$targetPath\$fileName" -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation
```

However, when I use the following line it doesn't:

```
Export-Csv -InputObject $csvBody -Path "$targetPath\$fileName" -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case, the output looks like this:
    Count,"Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized"
    263,"263","263","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False"

I understand from [this other Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459269/exporting-a-variable-to-a-csv-file) that the output becomes the property of the $csvBody, which is an array. My question is why does this happen when I'm not piping the object to Export-CSV, but it *doesn't* happen when I *am* using the pipe?

Comment: It is the same variable that I try to call with the two different approaches above. The output becomes either the actual contents of the variable (when using the pipe) or it becomes the property of the array (when not using the pipe). I'm guessing that it is something to do with some form of difference between using the variable as the -InputObject or just piping it, and my question is what this difference is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here everything works as design **and not badly written** :

In the second way, the inputobject is a `#TYPE System.Object[]` as you can see if you keep TypeInformation.

When you call Export-Csv using the pipe, each object of the collection is sent to the process part of the Cmdlet.

---

Take a collection of integers :

```
$a = 1..4
```

then try :

```
$a | Get-Member
```

It gives : `System.Int32`

Then try :

```
Get-Member -InputObject $a
```

It gives : `System.Object[]`

So in your case the object exported is the array wich can be useful too.

Comment: Am I interpreting you correctly that the explanation from Mark Wragg, namely that the -InputObject does not take arrays, is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: The "badly written", makes me reacting, because first, after five versions, if it was badly written it would have been corrected, second in the semantic of the CmdLet, you export an object, the object is an array, you receive an array it's ok. When you pipe objects into the Cmdlet you receive objects.

Comment: Several versions doesn't necessarily mean that bugs will be fixed, but I agree with you that if it is written to take a single object (i.e., not an array) then it is by design and not 'badly written'.

Comment: I will retract my "badly written" comment as it doesn't sit well with me. I do think PowerShell sometimes makes some misguided assumptions/defaults that can't then be corrected without breaking things for older scripts (such as -notypeinformation should be default on Export-CSV) but I think what I should have said (as I did at the end) that this was/is by design.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is because `Export-CSV` has been written with the intention that it should (and would) generally handle input via the pipeline.

I think the behavior you are seeing occurs because the `-InputObject` parameter does not accept array input. You can see that from the help page:

```
   Export-Csv [[-Path] <String>] [[-Delimiter] <Char>] [-Append] [-Confirm] [-Encoding <String> {Unicode | UTF7 |
   UTF8 | ASCII | UTF32 | BigEndianUnicode | Default | OEM}] [-Force] -InputObject <PSObject> [-LiteralPath <String>]
   [-NoClobber] [-NoTypeInformation] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

It is `<psobject>` rather than `<psobject[]>` and as such it expects a single `<psobject>` as it's input. It seemingly doesn't unroll that object when it's provided via the parameter line, instead it gives you a CSV that contains the default properties of that object itself (length etc.).

When you send the object via the pipeline, it uses the cmdlet `PROCESS` functionality of accepting pipeline input to unroll the object and handle each item in the collection individually.

Someone can probably explain this better than I have above, or perhaps can explain why Export-CSV doesn't work the way you expect (other than --as I assume-- by design).

Comment: Oh my, this has to be it. Thank you so much for clarifying this! I was scratching my head for way too long on this one :)