# Powershell Import/Export-csv group & join cells

Tags: powershell, import-csv, export-csv

I have a csv file which I need to group and join various cells together and have them then separated by a semi-colon in the csv layout is as such

[CSV Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64l0t.png)

I have managed to join the cells 'price' & 'functionnumber' together and separate them with a ';' but for 'datedespatched' and 'username' which just need to display the 1 name or date the cells return with 'System.Object[]' displayed in the condensed cell, the 'referencenumber' cell appears to condense down fine.
This is my current code and the output I receive from it

```
 Import-Csv 'C:\temp\test.csv' | Group-Object ReferenceNumber |ForEach-Object {
 
 [PsCustomObject]@{

        ReferenceNumber = $_.Name

        userName = $_.Group.userName

        DateDespatched = $_.Group.DateDespatched 

        functionnumber = $_.Group.functionnumber -join '; '

        Price = $_.Group.Price -join '; '
        
        }
 } | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\test-export.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

[Code-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g93EF.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does `$_.Group.DateDespatched[0]` and `$_.Group.Username[0]` work?

Comment: Do the same join for the other 2?

Comment: @NekoMusume Yup that worked! thank you

Comment: @DougMaurer I need the datedespatched and username to only show 1 in the box as they are always the same

Answer (score 1):

When you create your custom PS object you are joining the output of functionnumber and Price but not userName and DateDespatched. The effect this has is that the $_.Group.userName becomes an array, and you're sending the array as the object to output. If you add

```
-join ';'
```

to both username and DateDespatched it will work. I had a similar issue with this that I got some good help on [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737470/difference-between-using-and-not-using-pipe-in-export-csv-in-powershell).

If you want to only output one name per row, you could pipe the arrays to

```
Select-Object -Unique
```

to only get unique entries.

Comment: Thank you for this, I managed to resolve it with the $_.Group.DateDespatched[0] and $_.Group.Username[0] as recommended above by Neko

Comment: Great that it worked :) the [0] in that solution means that you only get the first entry in the array. As in, $_.Group.Username is an array, and [#] means get number # from that array. Note that that solution ignores situations where you have several different usernames for the same Referencenumber.